# Continuous input

Tags: python, input

How can I make continuous input? I want to the player be able to write *menu* any time he wants, not only on the start of the program?

```
print("\nWelcome to the nature center. What would you like to do?")
choice = ''
while choice != 'q':
    print("\n[1] Enter 1 to take a bicycle ride.")
    print("[2] Enter 2 to go for a run.")
    print("[3] Enter 3 to climb a mountain.")
    print("[q] Enter q to quit.")

choice = input("\nWhat would you like to do? ")

if choice == '1': 
    print("\nHere's a bicycle. Have fun!\n")
elif choice == '2':
    print("\nHere are some running shoes. Run fast!\n")
elif choice == '3':
    print("\nHere's a map. Can you leave a trip plan for us?\n")
elif choice == 'q':
    print("\nThanks for playing. See you later.\n")
else:
    print("\nI don't understand that choice, please try again.\n")
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What is "any time he wants"? There isn't even *one* `input` statement where the user can enter "menu" here. Maybe you just want to wrap this whole thing in a `while True:`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make also the "switch case" in your `while` :

```
print("\nWelcome to the nature center. What would you like to do?")
choice = ''
while choice != 'q':
    print("\n[1] Enter 1 to take a bicycle ride.")
    print("[2] Enter 2 to go for a run.")
    print("[3] Enter 3 to climb a mountain.")1
    print("[q] Enter q to quit.")

    choice = input("\nWhat would you like to do? ")

    if choice == '1': 
        print("\nHere's a bicycle. Have fun!\n")
    elif choice == '2':
        print("\nHere are some running shoes. Run fast!\n")
    elif choice == '3':
        print("\nHere's a map. Can you leave a trip plan for us?\n")
    elif choice == 'q':
        print("\nThanks for playing. See you later.\n")
    else:
        print("\nI don't understand that choice, please try again.\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your indentation is incorrect but you can just loop **forever** (`while True`) and then just `break` when you need to:

```
print("\nWelcome to the nature center. What would you like to do?")
while True: # Loop through indefinitely
    print("\n[1] Enter 1 to take a bicycle ride.")
    print("[2] Enter 2 to go for a run.")
    print("[3] Enter 3 to climb a mountain.")
    print("[q] Enter q to quit.")

    choice = input("\nWhat would you like to do? ")

    if choice == '1': 
        print("\nHere's a bicycle. Have fun!\n")
    elif choice == '2':
        print("\nHere are some running shoes. Run fast!\n")
    elif choice == '3':
        print("\nHere's a map. Can you leave a trip plan for us?\n")
    elif choice == 'q':
        print("\nThanks for playing. See you later.\n")
        break # Exit the loop here
    else:
        print("\nI don't understand that choice, please try again.\n")
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the nature center. What would you like to do?

[1] Enter 1 to take a bicycle ride.
[2] Enter 2 to go for a run.
[3] Enter 3 to climb a mountain.
[q] Enter q to quit.

What would you like to do? 1

Here's a bicycle. Have fun!


[1] Enter 1 to take a bicycle ride.
[2] Enter 2 to go for a run.
[3] Enter 3 to climb a mountain.
[q] Enter q to quit.

What would you like to do? 2

Here are some running shoes. Run fast!


[1] Enter 1 to take a bicycle ride.
[2] Enter 2 to go for a run.
[3] Enter 3 to climb a mountain.
[q] Enter q to quit.

What would you like to do? q

Thanks for playing. See you later.
```